# how to use try catch with constructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, try-catch

I saw many examples but I am not able to understand, how to use try catch with a simple constructor, I wrote a sample program:

```
class A
 {
   public:
    try {
       A()
        { cout << "in costr\n"; throw 10;}
    }//try closed
   catch (int a)
{ cout << "caught 1 \n"; }

 };

main()
 {
   A *ptr = new A;
   }
```

1. This program gives a compilation error
2. If exception is caught, what happens to object ??

Comment: Well since the code has a compilation error we can't answer question 2 because the code is meaningless.

Comment: Just a hint for the future, when asking a question about compilation error, add the _exact_ error messages to the question, and _all_ messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `try/catch` code is supposed to be *together,* you can't have one without the other. Something like this is what you're after:

```
A *ptr;
try {
    ptr = new A();
} catch (int a) {
    cout << "caught 1\n";
}
```

See the following program for a complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        A() { a = 7; throw 42; }
        int getA() { return a; }
};

int main (void) {
    A *ptr;
    try {
        ptr = new A();
    } catch (int b) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << b << '\n';
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Value: " << ptr->getA() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

With the `throw 42` in there, you see:

```
Exception: 42
```

meaning that `main` has caught the exception coming from the constructor. Without the `throw`, you see:

```
Value: 7
```

because everything has worked.

---

The main problems with your code seem to be:

- You have a `try` statement where it shouldn't be. `Try/catch` blocks should generally be *within* a function or method, you have it immediately after the `public` keyword.
- If you're throwing an exception from the constructor, you don't catch it in the constructor. Instead you catch it in the code that *called* the constructor (`main` in this case).
- As previously mentioned, `try` and `catch` go together, they're not standalone entities.

---

If you *are* trying to `throw` and `catch` within the constructor, you'll still need to put it *within* the constructor itself, something like:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        A() {
            try {
                a = 7;
                throw 42;
            } catch (int b) {
                std::cout << "Exception A: " << b << '\n';
                throw;
            }
        }
        int getA() {return a;}
};

int main(void) {
    A *ptr;
    try {
        ptr = new A();
    } catch (int b) {
        std::cout << "Exception B: " << b << '\n';
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Value: " << ptr->getA() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

which gives you:

```
Exception A: 42
Exception B: 42
```

Note *specifically* how the `try/catch` block is both complete and *within* the constructor function.

Comment: m trying to put try catch in class, it is illegal, as it shows compilation error : expected unqualified-id before 'try'

Comment: @user1160090 you need the try-catch block *inside a function* (such as the constructor). Yours is partially hanging out in the class declaration body.

Comment: @user1160090, your `try` is outside any code area, you need to put it inside some sort of function, not immediately after the `public`. It is executable code after all. In any case, if you're throwing an exception from the constructor, you _don't_ catch it in the constructor itself, you catch it in whatever _called_ the constructor. See my code for an example.

Answer (score 6):

The issue of exceptions raised during constructors is addressed by [function try blocks](http://www.drdobbs.com/introduction-to-function-try-blocks/184401297):

```
class A
 {
   public:
       A()
       try 
         { cout << "in costr\n"; throw 10;}
      catch(...)
        { cout << "exception caught"; throw;}
 };
```

But the scenario they are addressing is a different one from your example. Function try blocks are needed when the class constructor allocates resources that need to be reclaimed. Since the destructor of the class is not run if the constructor throw (there's nothing to destroy, the class did not construct to start with) one way to address the issue is using function try blocks on the constructor. Note that constructor function try blocks must re-throw an exception or the original exception, they cannot silence the exception caught.

For a more detailed discussion of the question you're asking (what is the scope/lifetime of an object in presence of exception during construcors) see [GOTW#66](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm).

Comment: Function-try-blocks for a constructor are never really "needed". It's an almost entirely useless feature.

Comment: @Kerrek-SB 

I just wrote one -- and not for cleaning up as I know RAII.
Just curious how you would state something like that, just because you cannot imagine a use case. C++ wasn't invented just for you!

Answer (score 5):

If what you want to do is deal with an exception thrown in the constructor without rethrowing it, then you have to place the try-catch block *inside* the constructor, or surrounding the constructos initialization list:

```
class A
 {
  public:
   A() {
     try {
       // some code that could throw int
       cout << "in costr\n"; throw 10;}
     }//try closed
     catch (int a) {
       cout << "caught 1 \n";
     }
   }
   explicit A(int i) try : functionThatCanThow(i) catch (int)
   { }

 };

main()
{
   A *ptr = new A;
   A* ptr2 = new A(5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        A() 
        {   
            std::cout << "in costr\n";

            // An exception
            // of type `int`
            throw int(10); 
        }   
};

int main()
{
    // A try block were something may go wrong.
    try 
    {   
        A *ptr = new A;
    }   
    // A try is followed by one or more catch blocks
    // that can be activated if an exception is thrown
    catch (int a)
    {   
        std::cout << "caught 1 \n";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put try and catch together...

```
class A
{
  public:
    A() { cout << "in costr\n"; throw 10; }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        A* ptr = new A;
    }
    catch (int a)
    {
        cout << "caught " << a << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: no no not like this ,m trying to put try catch in class, it is illegal, as it shows compilation error : expected unqualified-id before 'try'

Comment: You're trying to do that because you don't understand what they are.  A try catch block says "try doing this but if it doesn't work then do this instead".  Everything inside the try part is implicitly "tried", including the construction, so there's no need to put a try explicitly in the constructor - it's already covered.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers, if you want to check for exceptions during object construction itself, you could consider some construct like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

struct Base {
    Base() { 
        cout << "Inside Base()\n";
        throw 1;
    }

private: 
    int i_;
};

struct Member {
    Member(int i) : i_(i) { 
        cout << "Inside Member()\n";
        throw 2;
    }

private: 
    int i_;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    Derived(int) try : member_(55) { cout << "Inside try{}\n"; } catch(int) { cout << "Inside catch()\n"; }

private: 
  Member member_;
};

int main() {
    Derived d(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, see how throw from base is caught before any further construction attempts and this causes object construction to fail while providing sufficient information. In this case, it is a trivial example. In actual scenario, you might want to propagate your exception down the call-stack instead of swallowing it.